# Connecting an android program with database

Tags: android

I want to connect an android program with database(not mysql or sqlite).
   I want to use apache tocat server.
   Next i convert my android program into JSP(java server page).
   And i want to use the same database.( for jsp and also for android application)
so, 
   My question is that which database i need to use? 
   which is the best practice?
   and
   give me some guideline and good tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html. You can  create a server/client application, in the server side, you could connect to database and offer a Webservice that your application can use. In this aproach, you can use any database that suports java programming language.